# How to use lockf on command line

Tags: debian, files, filesystems, nfs, lock

I want to lock and unlock a file that resides in NFS share so I've found the reliable way is to go with `lockf` how can I use that in command line for `flock` I could  do 'flock -s number' how can I do that for `lockf`.And I am on debian when I do `lockf` it says no such command.

Comment: do you have `lockfile` on your system?

Comment: lockfile, yes just installed

Comment: but lockfile create new semaphore file isn't , but i want  to lock the filedes of a previously created file